# Determine whether $\sum_{t=2}^n\frac{\log t}{\Omega(t)}\sim n\log n$

Tags: prime-numbers, chebyshev-function

Determine whether $$\sum_{t=2}^n\dfrac{\log t}{\Omega(t)}\sim n\log n$$

Let $r=n^{1/\Omega(n)}$, where $n$ is a positive integer and $\Omega(n)$ is the total number of prime factors of $n$. If $r$ is an integer, then it is prime and $n=r^{\Omega(n)}$, otherwise $r$ is strictly between the least and greatest prime factors of $n$.

It seems natural to compare the sum

$$s(n)=\sum_{t=2}^n\dfrac{\log t}{\Omega(t)}$$

to the second Chebyshev function,

$$\psi(n)=\sum_{p^k\leq n}\log p$$

and it appears that $\dfrac{s(n)}{\psi(n)}\sim\log n$. By $n=150000$ the L.H.S. is only greater by a factor of about $1.10129$.

Edit: I had forgotten that $\psi(n)\sim n$, so what I want to show is that

$$\sum_{t=2}^n\dfrac{\log t}{\Omega(t)}\sim n\log n$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $$\sum_{t=2}^{n}\log\left(t\right)\sim n\log\left(n\right)$$
 and$$\Omega\left(n\right)\sim\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)$$
 as $n\rightarrow\infty$
  we have, by partial summation,$$\sum_{t=2}^{n}\frac{\log\left(t\right)}{\Omega\left(t\right)}\sim\sum_{t=2}^{n}\frac{\log\left(t\right)}{\log\left(\log\left(t\right)\right)}\sim\frac{n\log\left(n\right)}{\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)}+\int_{3}^{n}\frac{1}{\log\left(\log\left(y\right)\right)^{2}}dy.$$
 Now we can integrate by parts$$\int_{3}^{n}\frac{1}{\log\left(\log\left(y\right)\right)^{2}}dy=\left.\frac{y}{\log\left(\log\left(y\right)\right)^{2}}\right|_{3}^{n}+2\int_{3}^{n}\frac{y}{\log\left(\log\left(y\right)\right)^{3}y\log\left(y\right)}dy<\left.\frac{y}{\log\left(\log\left(y\right)\right)^{2}}\right|_{3}^{n}+2n\int_{3}^{n}\frac{1}{\log\left(\log\left(y\right)\right)y\log\left(y\right)}dy\sim\frac{n}{\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)^{2}}+2n\log\left(\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)\right)$$
 so the integral gives a minor contribution than the first term. Hence$$\sum_{t=2}^{n}\frac{\log\left(t\right)}{\Omega\left(t\right)}\sim\frac{n\log\left(n\right)}{\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)}$$
 as $n\rightarrow\infty.$

Comment: Honestly my experience with calculus is a little over a year (when I woke up in time) in high school. I can't say I really understand this proof at all, but I appreciate and accept it. Does it mean the answer is the same for $\sum_{t=2}^n\dfrac{\log t}{\omega(n)}$ (as I believe $\omega(n)\sim\log\log n$ as well)?

Comment: Yes, $\omega$ and $\Omega$ have the same asymptotic.